# When creating an Android intent and specifying target activity, what is this ".class" syntax?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is, perhaps, a stupid question, but I've found nothing on it elsewhere. I'm going through the basics of Android, and when I try to create an intent specifically to run another activity of my choosing, the tutorial tells me to construct it this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Where "DisplayMessageActivity" is the class for the activity I'm running. What I don't get is, what's the ".class" part? That parameter, as I understand it, is supposed to be a Class object. Is "class" a field of my Activity subclass? Or when I say "DisplayMessageActivity.class", am I referring to an actual .class file (that seems a little weird)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the `.class` appears to be a normal field access, it is actually a special language construct, that is explained very well in the [Retrieving Class Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) Java tutorial.

It says, quote:

> *If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible to obtain a Class by appending ".class" to the name of the type. This is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.*

And they give the example:

```
boolean b;
Class c = b.getClass();   // compile-time error

Class c = boolean.class;  // correct
```

In my day to day usage of Java, this isn't a hugely used construct, and many are unaware of it. Generally it's used with generics and the like when specificing classes in general rather than instances of them.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

> What I don't get is, what's the ".class" part?  That parameter, as I understand it, is supposed to be a Class object.

That is correct.

The `SomeClass.class` is actually Java syntax that means "give me the `Class` object that corresponds to the `SomeClass` type".  And note that you can use it on any type ... not just class names.

> Is "class" a field of my Activity subclass?

No.  It is not a field.  You could think of it as analogous to a static field, but actually it is no such thing.  (Just like `someArray.length` is not really a field of the array object.)

> Or when I say "DisplayMessageActivity.class", am I referring to an actual .class file

It is referring to a `Class` *object* ... not a ".class" file.